# How to implement login process by segue in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am a complete beginner in iOS development and I was creating a login form that goes to next page by segue method when I enter "admin" as username and password. But it's not working accordingly and just moving to secondviewcontroller.

[image]

For the first page which has username, password and login option:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  loginFormAssignment
//
//  Created by Piyush Kapoor on 2020-06-17.
//  Copyright © 2020 Piyush Kapoor. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    var str = "admin"
    var pass = "admin"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func sendPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if str.contains(self.username!.text!) && pass.contains(self.password!.text!){
           performSegue(withIdentifier: "toLogin", sender: self)
        }            
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? secondViewController{
            destination.user = username.text!            
            }
    }
}
For the secondviewcontroller page which has only label to print message:
//
//  secondViewController.swift
//  loginFormAssignment
//
//  Created by Piyush Kapoor on 2020-06-17.
//  Copyright © 2020 Piyush Kapoor. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class secondViewController: UIViewController {
    var user = ""
    @IBOutlet weak var resultLbl: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        resultLbl.text = user 
    }        
}
```

Comment: can you add code here what you try?

Comment: yes I have added the code

Comment: "But it's not working accordingly and just moving to secondviewcontroller." Isn't that what you want? If it's not what you want, what _do_ you want?

Comment: I want that when my username and password is "admin" on both text fields, then only it goes to second view controller, else it gives me error and stays on same page.

Answer (score 0):

check identifier for prepare for segue method 
and check also you have correct identifier

```
 @IBAction func sendPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if self.username.text ?? "" == "admin" && self.password.text ?? "" == "admin" {
           performSegue(withIdentifier: "toLogin", sender: self)
        }

    }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toLogin" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? secondViewController{
            destination.user = username.text!            
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've already added segue from `LoginVC` to `SecondVC` then you can't check condition if user has entered anything or not.

**Let me explain you why not to use segue here...**

Here we are performing login action on button click. And if you already added segue to this button to secondViewController, then `onClick` event it will just `performSegue` to next viewController.

That's why, I prefer to navigate using `NavigationController`.

> Before implementing, this solution, remove/delete segue that you added to `secondViewController`.

You already had a Navigation controller...so better to use navigationController to navigate to particular viewController if condition is full-filled.

**Solution :**

```
@IBAction func sendPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if self.userNameText.text ?? "" == str && self.passwordText.text ?? "" == pass {
            guard let vc = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController else {
                print("Could not instantiate view controller with identifier of type SecondViewController")
                return
            }

            vc.user = self.userNameText.text
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated:true)
        }
    }
```

> Make sure you give proper identifier to your `secondViewController` i.e "SecondViewController"

Here you can...

- pass data,
- check condition,
- accordingly navigate to particular view controller.
- stays on same `viewController`, if condition doesn't full-fill.

Hope it helps you to understand.